# Angular js ng-click doesn't work in child element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to toggle a variable on click of an element in the DOM and I'm getting some strange behaviour.

**[Full Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xsiah/Xya3f/1/)**

Essentially if I put the **ng-click** on the *.options* div and leave the controller on the *.options-tab* div, the event triggers (but applies to everything inside the *.options* div). And for some reason I am forced to apply the ng-controller again.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Swipe" class="container">
    <div class="options" ng-click="swiped=!swiped2">
         <div ng-controller="Swipe" class="options-tab" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I put it on the element that I want it on, it doesn't trigger the event.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Swipe" class="container">
    <div class="options">
         <div ng-controller="Swipe" class="options-tab" ng-click="swiped=!swiped2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you applying the same controller twice? This will create two scopes.

Comment: I know, it's bizarre. It won't work in either case if I don't. Remove it in the JSFiddle and see for yourself. I need the scope at the top, because an element above the one I'm clicking on needs to see the change in the variable, but I would love to be able to get rid of the second one.

Comment: You can't use a controller inside of itself of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few issues:

1. Multiple controller declarations creating duplicate scopes
2. `ng-click="swiped1=!swiped1"` on both the `options` and `options-tab` elements (it was being set and then reversed immediately)
3. Your 2nd example was set to `ng-click="swiped=!swiped2"` instead of `ng-click="swiped2=!swiped2"`

Updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xya3f/2/